# React Native Intercom - Invariant Violation

Tags: ios, react-native, intercom

I am using react-native-intercom to manage Intercom in my app. I have installed the Intercom iOS SDK using CocoaPods, and linked the react-native-intercom manually (didn't work when using react-native link). Problem though is when I insert it into a container, then I am getting the error message when it loads:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in component) or a class/function (for composite components) but
>   got: object.

However, if I then dismiss the error, Intercom shows up fine e.g. if I have:

```
componentWillMount () {
    Intercom.displayConversationsList()
}
```

Then after dismissing the error, my messages would appear and it would work, so I'm guessing the installation and linking are okay. I've tried doing a clean npm install, but same thing happens, won't load without the error.

My render just looks like this as I'm just testing it on a blank page:

```
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Intercom />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

I'm actually just assuming that this is how you call Intercom inside a render, as I couldn't find any examples.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you have installed intercom using CocoaPods ? I am developing an app in react native and wanted to install intercom on app. please suggest how i can do ? thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: @ShashankShah it was a bit tricky to get it working, but I used the instructions from here: https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/ios-installation to do it. You add to the pods file then do pod install, and it installs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `<Intercom />` component.

Comment: Thanks very much, that stopped the error coming up. One follow-up question, do you know how to get the main circle appear, from which the user can click and show the full Intercom? That doesn't appear, and if I set something initially like Intercom.displayConversationsList(), then close the list, it's not there after closing.

Comment: Just answered my own question... Intercom.setLauncherVisibility('VISIBLE')

Comment: Glad you figured it out :D